# Creating “Run over by car” effect in unity using spotlights only

Tags: unity, 3d, lighting

I'm doing a project where I need to simulate a car running the character over. It's happening in a completely dark space, so I want to create it using spotlights moving towards the camera until the screen gets completely white.

To create this "bright light" effect, I use volametric lighting on 2 spotlights:
[image]

But when I start moving the spotlights towards the player, the spotlights start moving away from each other (Which makes sense, and can be fixed somewhat by increasing the SpotAngle/Range by code while the spotlights are moving).
[image]

However, when the spotlights get to right in front of the player, they disappear before making the screen completely white. I could use a fade-in complete white screen transition, but this complete method seems extremely clunky. Is there another, better way, or maybe a simpler fix to my spotlight moving closer issue?

Comment: have you tried rotating them inwards as the car gets closer? you could also on a specific distance stop coming closer and actually moving the lights closer to eachother and increasing their brightness.

Comment: sounds like the clipping plane on the camera. If the near is still at it's default of 0.3, lower it to something like 0.00001. If that is not quite enough you could flash a UI panel at the end.